# Join columns in LINQ and run contains operator

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms

I'm trying to create a search method where I'm wanting to check whether the keywords is contained within a any of number of different columns for a given record.

My Linq statement is as follows:

```
string[] searchFilter = {"john", "iceberg"};


var q = from qua in qual
                    join del in deliverables on qua.ID equals del.Q_ID
                    where searchFilter.All(s => (qua.Name + " " + qua.Project + " " + qua.Summary + " " + del.Name + " " + del.Summary).ToLower().Contains(s))
                    select qua;
```

I'm however getting an error message which states: "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator."

Comment: So, what is the question? The exception is pretty self-explaining - you have a local sequence (read: in-memory), and you cannot use that in a linq-query with L2S, except when you use it with the Contains()-operator. You are using the All-operator, so you cannot use local sequences in your query.

Comment: Can you possibly suggest an alternative approach to the above problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contains method for whatever reason was not using the filtered results when it came through the loop a second time around. The approach that eventually worked was:

```
var SearchColumn = from qua in Qual
               join del in deliverables on qua.Q_ID equals del.Q_ID into left_j
                            from del in left_j.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new { qua.Name + " " + qua.Project + " " + qua.Summary + " " + del.Name + " " + del.Summary).ToLower() };

foreach (var f in searchFilter)
{
   var likestr = string.Format("%{0}%", f);
   SearchColumn = SearchColumn.Where(x => SqlMethods.Like(x.Search_Col, likestr));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can't use the All method but just the Contains method:

```
var q = from qua in qual
        join del in deliverables on qua.ID equals del.Q_ID
        where searchFilter.Contains(qua.Name) ||  searchFilter.Contains(qua.Project)...
        select qua;
```

Of course you can combine your linq query dynamically with expressions (but it could be much more work), or use dynamic linq.

Comment: This will not produce the same result. For a record with Name = 'johnx', your query will not return the result, but the query from the OP will (or, that is the intention). Also the .All operator will only return if ALL items in the sequence apply, which is something Contains doesn't do.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you have choice :

But as you stay in a "Queryable" world, this will generate only one sql request (ugly, but...)

```
var q = from qua in qual
        join del in deliverables on qua.ID equals del.Q_ID
        select new{ qua, del};

foreach (var filter in searchFilter)
     q = q.Where(v => (v.qua.Name + " " + v.qua.Project + " " + v.qua.Summary + " " + v.del.Name + " " + v.del.Summary).ToLower().Contains(filter));

var result = q.Select(p => p.qua);
```

Comment: Similar to Amiram answer, this will not return results matching all the items within the array.

Comment: Just tried it out. Odd thing is that when it comes around the loop the second time around it doesn't use the filtered results from the first pass through, instead uses the original results. :S